# Error in Python Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I keep getting an error when I run this python program,
It says I don't have any file or directory at '/path/to/times-testing.log'.
I don't seem to understand, can anyone help me in fixing this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Heres the code:

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import time
import sys, os
import logging
from urllib2 import HTTPError
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser


# helper function to iterate through dates
def daterange( start_date, end_date ):
    if start_date <= end_date:
        for n in range( ( end_date - start_date ).days + 1 ):
            yield start_date + datetime.timedelta( n )
    else:
        for n in range( ( start_date - end_date ).days + 1 ):
            yield start_date - datetime.timedelta( n )

# helper function to get json into a form I can work with       
def convert(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {convert(key): convert(value) for key, value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [convert(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input

# helpful function to figure out what to name individual JSON files        
def getJsonFileName(date, page, json_file_path):
    json_file_name = ".".join([date,str(page),'json'])
    json_file_name = "".join([json_file_path,json_file_name])
    return json_file_name

# helpful function for processing keywords, mostly    
def getMultiples(items, key):
    values_list = ""
    if len(items) > 0:
        num_keys = 0
        for item in items:
            if num_keys == 0:
                values_list = item[key]                
            else:
                values_list =  "; ".join([values_list,item[key]])
            num_keys += 1
    return values_list

# get the articles from the NYTimes Article API    
def getArticles(date, query, api_key, json_file_path):
    # LOOP THROUGH THE 101 PAGES NYTIMES ALLOWS FOR THAT DATE
    for page in range(101):
        for n in range(5): # 5 tries
            try:
                request_string = "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json?begin_date=" + date + "&end_date=" + date + "&page=" + str(page) + "&api-key=" + api_key
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request_string)
                content = response.read()
                if content:
                    articles = convert(json.loads(content))
                    # if there are articles here
                    if len(articles["response"]["docs"]) >= 1:
                        json_file_name = getJsonFileName(date, page, json_file_path)
                        json_file = open(json_file_name, 'w')
                        json_file.write(content)
                        json_file.close()
                    # if no more articles, go to next date
                    else:
                        return
                time.sleep(3) # wait so we don't overwhelm the API
            except HTTPError as e:
                logging.error("HTTPError on page %s on %s (err no. %s: %s) Here's the URL of the call: %s", page, date, e.code, e.reason, request_string)
                if e.code == 403:
                    print "Script hit a snag and got an HTTPError 403. Check your log file for more info."
                    return
                if e.code == 429:
                    print "Waiting. You've probably reached an API limit."
                    time.sleep(30) # wait 30 seconds and try again
            except: 
                logging.error("Error on %s page %s: %s", date, file_number, sys.exc_info()[0])
                continue

# parse the JSON files you stored into a tab-delimited file
def parseArticles(date, tsv_file_name, json_file_path):

    for file_number in range(101):
        # get the articles and put them into a dictionary
        try:
            file_name = getJsonFileName(date,file_number, json_file_path)
            if os.path.isfile(file_name):
                in_file = open(file_name, 'r')
                articles = convert(json.loads(in_file.read()))
                in_file.close()
            else:
                break
        except IOError as e:
            logging.error("IOError in %s page %s: %s %s", date, file_number, e.errno, e.strerror)
            continue

        # if there are articles in that document, parse them
        if len(articles["response"]["docs"]) >= 1:  

            # open the tsv for appending
            try:
                out_file = open(tsv_file_name, 'ab')

            except IOError as e:
                logging.error("IOError: %s %s %s %s", date, file_number, e.errno, e.strerror)
                continue

            # loop through the articles putting what we need in a tsv   
            try:
                for article in articles["response"]["docs"]:
                    # if (article["source"] == "The New York Times" and article["document_type"] == "article"):
                    keywords = ""
                    keywords = getMultiples(article["keywords"],"value")

                    # should probably pull these if/else checks into a module
                    variables = [
                        article["pub_date"], 
                        keywords, 
                        str(article["headline"]["main"]).decode("utf8").replace("\n","") if "main" in article["headline"].keys() else "", 
                        str(article["source"]).decode("utf8") if "source" in article.keys() else "", 
                        str(article["document_type"]).decode("utf8") if "document_type" in article.keys() else "", 
                        article["web_url"] if "web_url" in article.keys() else "",
                        str(article["news_desk"]).decode("utf8") if "news_desk" in article.keys() else "",
                        str(article["section_name"]).decode("utf8") if "section_name" in article.keys() else "",
                        str(article["snippet"]).decode("utf8").replace("\n","") if "snippet" in article.keys() else "",
                        str(article["lead_paragraph"]).decode("utf8").replace("\n","") if "lead_paragraph" in article.keys() else "",
                        ]
                    line = "\t".join(variables)
                    out_file.write(line.encode("utf8")+"\n")
            except KeyError as e:
                logging.error("KeyError in %s page %s: %s %s", date, file_number, e.errno, e.strerror)
                continue
            except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                raise
            except: 
                logging.error("Error on %s page %s: %s", date, file_number, sys.exc_info()[0])
                continue

            out_file.close()
        else:
            break

# Main function where stuff gets done

def main():

    config = SafeConfigParser()
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'config/settings.cfg')
    config.read(config_file)

    json_file_path = config.get('files','json_folder')
    tsv_file_name = config.get('files','tsv_file')
    log_file = config.get('files','logfile')

    api_key = config.get('nytimes','api_key')    
    start = datetime.date( year = int(config.get('nytimes','start_year')), month = int(config.get('nytimes','start_month')), day = int(config.get('nytimes','start_day')) )
    end = datetime.date( year = int(config.get('nytimes','end_year')), month = int(config.get('nytimes','end_month')), day = int(config.get('nytimes','end_day')) )
    query = config.get('nytimes','query')

    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, level=logging.INFO)

    logging.info("Getting started.") 
    try:
        # LOOP THROUGH THE SPECIFIED DATES
        for date in daterange( start, end ):
            date = date.strftime("%Y%m%d")
            logging.info("Working on %s." % date)
            getArticles(date, query, api_key, json_file_path)
            parseArticles(date, tsv_file_name, json_file_path)
    except:
        logging.error("Unexpected error: %s", str(sys.exc_info()[0]))
    finally:
        logging.info("Finished.")

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    main()
```

It generates the following error when compiling it:

```
Rakeshs-MacBook-Air:get-nytimes-articles-master niharika$ python getTimesArticles.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getTimesArticles.py", line 180, in <module>
    main()
  File "getTimesArticles.py", line 164, in main
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, level=logging.INFO)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1545, in basicConfig
    hdlr = FileHandler(filename, mode)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 911, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 941, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/times-testing.log'
Rakeshs-MacBook-Air:get-nytimes-articles-master niharika$
```

Comment: maby the logfile dont exist touch the log file 'touch /path/to/times-testing.log'

Comment: What is the content of the file config/settings.cfg ? In particular, what is the value associated with key logfile ? Does the corresponding file exists on the disk ?

Comment: Yes, I have settings.cfc at /desktop/nytpy/config/settings.cfc

Comment: Should I show the code of settings.cfc?

Answer (score 0):

Your `main()` function:

```
def main():

    config = SafeConfigParser()
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_file = os.path.join(script_dir, 'config/settings.cfg')
    config.read(config_file)
    ...
    log_file = config.get('files','logfile')
    ...
    logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file, level=logging.INFO)
```

opens the `config/settings.cfg` file and fetches the name of the log file, which seems to be `/path/to/times-testing.log`. You either need to create that folder (probably not the best idea) or configure it to point to the correct file.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very insightful, I have located the settings.cfg file, there is a parameter which specifies,                                            logfile = /path/to/times-testing.log
json_folder = /full/path/
tsv_file = /full/path/output.tsv   ,   should i create new empty files, i.e , output.tsv and times-testing.log files  and add the path ?  What should I set for the Json_folder parameter, Thank you!

Comment: Well, it's all up to you and where you want those files to be located, really. :) Normally logs are stored in the `/var/log/` folder on UNIX systems (such as macOS).